# MapKit - get location/address of business

Tags: ios, geolocation, mapkit

Im working on an app which requires the lat/long to display an annotation on a map. The user should be able to search for a business name and a allow him/her to select the correct one ...once he selects a pin annotation should be display on a map.

Currently I am able to search for a specific address using a search bar. I'm also able to display the pin annotation on the map. Is there a way to get the address and location for a business just like Uber and Lyft do it. For example, If i type the name of restaurant what is the best way to display restaurant options and 2. get the actual location (lat/long) and address for this restaurant.

Do we need to use an API like Google FourSquare etc?

Comment: If you don`t have a database with all the locations, you probably need to use an external api.

Comment: You should be able to get all the info you need, (address, coord, etc.) by using `MKLocalSearchRequest`  The search request will return places as  `MKMapItem` The `MKMapItem.placemark` will contain the info you are looking for.

Comment: MKLocalSearch works, for queries in natural language. I got it to return restaurants, coffee etc. But I really would like to get the location for specific venues. I think I might have to use an external API for this.